# Android - Refresh/restart all tab fragments when selected/reselected

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

once again, I am following this tutorial: [androidhive - tab layout with swipe able views](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/) . All 3 fragment tabs are loaded with different information and logic and layouts. I would like to refresh each fragment when their tabs have been clicked as it auto loads the fragments from start as it uses the view pager. Is there any simplest way out that I could load only a/1 fragment using view pager? Or to reload the fragments? Thanks for your help!

Comment: **Loading a viewpager when the page is selected is an error in architecture.**  Here's the problem.  The user will swipe the page and the page refresh will cause the app to be sluggish.
Answer there is no simple way to refresh a viewpagers current page.  I guess the answer of pagelimit(0) does work but the app will be sluggish.

Comment: the page limit(0) doesn't work though. it returned this warning: "Requested offscreen page limit 0 too small; defaulting to 1"

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your viewpager:

> MY_VIEWPAGER.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);

Check out the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29).

> Pages beyond this limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed.

The limit of 0 will cause a recreation of the fragment when you open a tab.

Comment: Hey there.. It doesn't work though. It returned this warning: "Requested offscreen page limit 0 too small; defaulting to 1"